# AS3 making nested mc buttons/textinputs visible/unvisible during runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm looking for an efficient way to hide and unhide movie clip buttons/text inputs which are all within a main mc. My application has a "help popup" which when enabled should turn off any buttons/text inputs at that current frame and when the help popup is closed the buttons/text inputs should be re-enabled.
I created the following function to disable/enable all buttons within my mainScreen mc which works great except my text inputs are not tabable any more after re-enabling them (It works 100% running the .swf file by itself but not within a browser):
And not all buttons should be visible depending on which keyframe one is on. I've been just manually placing the buttons/text inputs I need on each frame but if I create a global function that hides them and unhides them shouldn't they all be on frame one and on?

```
function disableButtons():void
{
mainScreen.mouseChildren = false;
mainScreen.tabChildren = false;
}
function enableButton():void
{
mainScreen.mouseChildren = true;
mainScreen.tabChildren = true;
}
```

I've explored the idea of placing all buttons in an array and then making them not visible and visible with a loop but then how would I specify which ones should be the visible ones according to the frame they are at:

```
var bArray:Array = [mainScreen.b1,mainScreen.txt2];
//When help popup is on hide all buttons
function hideButtons():void
{
for (var i:int = 0; i<bArray.length; i++)
{
    bArray[i].visible = false; 
}
}
//When help popup is closed only make visible the needed buttons
function showButtons():void
{
for (var i:int = 0; i<bArray.length; i++)
{
    bArray[i].visible = true; //Somehow I need to specify which ones I want visible depending on the frame.  

}
}
```

I still have a lot to learn, I appreciate any pointers!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make objects visible by their frame position, you can loop as many `.numChildren` and make it so given they are already in the display list

For example,

```
function makeInvisible ()
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < mainScreen.numChildren; i++)
        mainScreen.getChildAt (i).visible = false
        ;
}
```

You would want to call this function **in the frame you want to make object invisible**.

Of course, there's a catch. This function will make every object of `mainScreen` in the corresponding frame to be invisible. To get around this, you can filter the type of the object you want to render it invisible.

```
function makeInvisible ()
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < mainScreen.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var child = mainScreen.getChildAt (i);
        if (child is /*...insert type here...*/)
            child.visible = false;
    }
}
```